# Importing delimited text and applying style using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I have managed to cobble together two Python snippets, one to import multiple delimited files, and another to apply a style. What I would like to do is combine these into one operation, and if possible assign a group for them (creating it ideally if it doesn't exist)....

The below is what I have so far:

```
import os.path, glob
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer
layers=[]
for file in glob.glob('C:/PathToFiles/*.QGIS'): # Change this base path and change backslashes to forward slashes
  uri = "file:///" + file + "?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&useHeader=no&crs=epsg:27039" % (" ","field_8","field_9") #(Delimeter, XField, YField) #1st column in file is column 1
  vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, os.path.basename(file), "delimitedtext")
  vlayer.setFieldAlias(1,'X') #these order of columns go: 0, 1, 2 etc
  vlayer.setFieldAlias(2,'Y')
  layers.append(vlayer)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers(layers)
```

And:

```
from qgis.core import *
def applystyle_group(name):
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    point = root.findGroup(name) #Find Group AP
    for child in point.children():
        if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
            if child.layer().type()==0:
                child.layer().loadNamedStyle('C:/PathToStyle/POINT_CODE.qml')
applystyle_group("SPS Files")
```

As you can see, the group I am operating in is called 'SPS Files'.